# Модели из полигонов с 4+ вершинами в Unity

Tags: unity3d, 3d

- Как хорошо unity работает с N-гонами?
- Какие основные плюсы отказа от N-гонов?
- И есть ли
  существенная разница если работать только с треугольными полигонами?

Comment: 4 вопроса в одном, про N-гоны еще можно объединить, про формат лучше [задать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Как хорошо unity работает с N-гонами?

Никак он с ними не работает, никакой игровой движок не работает с n-гонами. Hardware (GPU) рендерит картинку только с помощью треугольников.

Почему?

Если бы чисто теоретически n-гон можно было бы обрабатывать на железе, как бы это, по-вашему, работало? Железо нельзя менять на ходу, оно всегда поддерживает конечный набор операций и дружит с определенным "форматом" данных. Так и зачем в итоге поддерживать какие-то экзотические штуки и тратить на них транзисторы и в целом площадь кристалла, если все эти ресурсы можно потратить на ядра/встроенные в железо функции?

Однако и это не самая важная причина, в треугольниках важнее всего их **гибкость**: из треугольников можно сделать квадрат, из них можно сделать вообще что угодно, но не наоборот.

Еще одним очень важным фактором является трехмерность нашего мира и, как следствие, графики. 3 точки всегда **гарантированно** лежат в одной плоскости, чего нельзя гарантировать для 4х точек и уж тем более для 5+ точек. Вот эта гарантия позволяет осуществлять интерполяцию между вершинами без особых заморочек. Да и плоскость гарантирует одинаковый вектор нормали по всей поверхности, если не затрагивать карты нормалей. У n-гонов при n > 3 такого бонуса нет.

Ну хорошо, **допустим**, GPU могут рендерить quad'ы нативно, и вы создаете 3д модели из quad'ов, у которых все точки лежат в одной плоскости. Что делать с анимацией? Буквально любая анимация может сломать эти "гарантии".

---

### Какие основные плюсы отказа от N-гонов?

N-гоны - это лишь абстракция, в конечном счете все модели триангулируются. Вы просто физически не сможете отрендерить полигоны с 4+ вершинами на современных GPU. Раньше были попытки в 4-гоны от nvidia, но это было давно и не увенчалось успехом.

---

### И есть ли существенная разница если работать только с треугольными полигонами?

Моделируйте хоть с какими полигонами, это не так важно, при импорте в Unity импортер преобразует все полигоны в треугольники, если сможет, разумеется.